# Deploy a js app on a mac

Tags: javascript, macos, installation, add-in

I have a js file that I need to create an installer for deployment on mac.
This is an addin for adobe reader so it simply needs to be placed in the appropriate folder on the target machine. Unfortunately, I know nothing about deploying on mac. I do not even own one.

Any simple ideas?

Answer (score 0):

[This topic](http://answers.acrobatusers.com/Where-javascript-folder-located-q73889.aspx) suggests that the directories are:

```
/Users/USER/Library/Application/Support/Adobe/Acrobat/11.0/JavaScripts (with USER being your user name)
```

and

```
/Applications/Adobe Acrobat XI Pro/Adobe Acrobat Pro.app/Contents/Resources/JavaScripts/
```

And from [here](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/951231) you could find out the following locations:

Reader 9:

```
/Macintosh HD/Applications/Adobe Acrobat 9 Pro/Adobe Acrobat Pro.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaScripts/
```

Reader 10:

```
/Macintosh HD/Applications/Adobe Reader.app/Contents/Resources/JavaScripts/
```

More information on topic could be found [here](http://khkonsulting.com/2010/12/acrobat-javascripts-where-do-they-go/).

According to many posts (including some of those you can find in this answer) you could also run the following command in the terminal on some mac (but then you should ask some help from a mac-user): `app.getPath("user", "javascript");`, and it will yield the required directory.

This command: `app.getPath("app","javascript");` also may help you if the first one did not work.

Comment: It is not a stand alone desktop application but rather an addin for adobe reader and adobe acrobat. I have a js file that simply needs to be placed in the correct folder on the target machine. Does that clarify the question?

Comment: Dear @user2251243, I have updated the answer with the information you may be looking for!